# How can I prevent duplicates with try and except blocks?

Tags: python

I have a list of urls, which contain JSON files.

The JSON files are all stored differently, therefore I need try and except blocks to cover the different storing methods.
The problem is that this method leads to some duplicates, because some links get requested two times  or more in the different blocks.

My code:

```
for line in urls:
    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        #textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        #textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten0 = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten0)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten0 = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten0)
    except:
        pass
```

Is it possible to write the try/except blocks in a way that a link gets ignored, if it was succesfully requested in a previous block?

Comment: Well, you can just move the try blocks inside the except block. Easy fix.

Comment: The real duplication here is not in `try ... except`, but in the pretty much the same code that is within. Once you extract it to a function, you can make it a nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it for you

```
for line in urls:
    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        #textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten)
        continue
    except:
        pass

    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        #textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten0 = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten0)
        continue
    except:
        pass

    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
        textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
        daten0 = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        r_urls.append(daten0)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You could also just put `continue` instead of `done = true` and remove the if statments.

Comment: @CDJB: I have updated my answer as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The first 2 `try/except` blocks are explicitly duplicated and there's no functional benefit to repeat them.

Instead, think through **2** consecutive phases:

- extracting a remote resource
- parsing JSON string and storing the result

So when *extracting* phase is failed - no sense to move forward, if the 1st *parsing* phase is failed - try another kind of parsing:

```
for line in urls:
    try:
        response = requests.get(line)
        textinhalt = response.text
    except:
        continue
    try:
        try:
            daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])
        except:
            textinhalt = textinhalt.split("__IR_CURRPAGE_DATA_JSON__")[1]
            daten = json.loads(textinhalt[textinhalt.find("{"):textinhalt.rfind("}")+1])

        r_urls.append(daten)
    except:
        pass
```